# Firebase login with facebook how to segue

Tags: swift, facebook, firebase, swift2

I have followed firebases new tutorial along with facebook into authenticating a user through facebook.

I do not know what to do next as the tutorial just ends....

this is what i have

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 25.0/255.0, green: 25.0/255.0, blue: 25.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)


    var loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()



    let midx = self.view.center.x


    loginButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(midx, 400.0)
    self.view!.addSubview(loginButton)


}


    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError?) {
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
}
```

it successfully logs me in but does not perform the segue..i have tried also with an else statment

i am new to facebook and firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had exactly the same problem

did you set the delegate ?? , if you did it programmatically , try it also on the storyboard

go to the login button and click drag to the top little orange box

and choose delegate!

in my case i did delegate it programmatically but it didn't work so i changed to the manual way of doing it !!

and now it works ...

Comment: this is my first time creating a button programatically, what is the delegate for a uiButton..i googled it and it says there is none

Comment: well in this case it is not a UIButton , it is a Facebook login button , you create the button on storyboard and give it a class: FBSDKLoginButton , then the delegate is FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate

Answer (score 1):

So The problem from what I can see is that you are calling the return function, after which nothing gets called. So try removing return or try using the provided code below:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    fbLogin.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]

    fbLogin.delegate = self

}
```

Try this in your "func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)" section

```
{

    if error == nil
    {
        print("Login complete.")





        let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
            // ...
        }

        let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
        if(accessToken != nil) //should be != nil
        {

        let req = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email,name,age_range,devices,hometown,gender,work"], tokenString: accessToken.tokenString, version: nil, HTTPMethod: "GET")
        req.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error : NSError!) -> Void in
            if(error == nil)
            {
                print("result \(result)")
            }
            else
            {
                print("error \(error)")
            }
        })


             self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: nil)


        }else{
            let loginFBAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Your login to facebook was interupted", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)


            loginFBAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
                self.pressedCancelOnAlert()
            }))
            presentViewController(loginFBAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        print("successfully done")


    }
    else
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }

}
```

That should work hundreds. Let me know if theres a problem but I have mine setup like this.

Comment: strange...and assigning the delegate?

Comment: oh I just saw @ismael33 suggested that